# eclipse / android project - file encoding issue while change package name

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an android project with eclipse, and I changed it's default package name in AndroidManifest.xml. It's strange that all sources in this project, all UTF-8 character displayed wrong with unknown character, it's like the file messed up.

I googled a lot, also change all files to UTF-8 it doesn't work, then I changed the default setting to UTF-8 in eclipse too, doesn't work too. I am running eclipse on Mac OSX 10.7 now.

If anyone can help, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you use eclipse I would suggest to change the package name from android tools. Right click on your project --> Android Tools --> Rename Application Package.